# Asp.net generic data binding method for Web UI controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I am trying to write a generic method that would bind any asp.net UI controls (drop down-list, list box.. etc)
Here is how I envision how the method should looks like:

```
public static void  AnyUIObjectDataBinder(Object anyUIcontrol, int id, string dataTextField, string dataValueField)
{
    anyUIcontrol.DataSource = GetList(id);
    anyUIcontrol.DataTextField = dataTextField;
    anyUIcontrol.DataValueField = dataValueField;
    anyUIcontrol.DataBind();
}
```

I would love to know if it is possible to have such method that accept any asp.net UI controls and set its binding property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try as

```
public static void  AnyUIObjectDataBinder(ListControl anyUIcontrol, int id, string dataTextField, string dataValueField)
{
    anyUIcontrol.DataSource = GetList(id);
    anyUIcontrol.DataTextField = dataTextField;
    anyUIcontrol.DataValueField = dataValueField;
    anyUIcontrol.DataBind();
}
```